# PlayonLinux won´t launch

Tags: playonlinux

PlayonLinux won't launch i tried everything i could find on google to fix the error but nothing seemed to do the job.

```
Looking for python3... 3.10.13 - selected
1.0520833333333333
xkbcommon: ERROR: failed to add default include path /home/adam/anaconda3/share/X11/xkb
xkbcommon: ERROR: failed to add default include path /home/adam/anaconda3/share/X11/xkb
/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux: regel 126: 1671817 Segmentatiefout         (geheugendump gemaakt) "$POL_PYTHON" mainwindow.py "$@"
```

How do i fix this issue?